# How to delete using cgridview from yii framework

Tags: yii-extensions

I not getting  to delete from `cgridview` in yii,its showing:

> Error 400,invalid request!

This is my controller code

```
public function actionDelete($id)

{
    //echo "helo";
    $model=new DiscountService();
    $model->deleteDService($id);
    $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Code in acess rules of controller

```
array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
            //'expression'=>'Yii::app()->controller->isAdmin()',
    ),
```

Please help in finding solution for deleting in cgrid view procedurely,

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "filters" method in your controller? (with 'postOnly + delete') ??

your delete link must be: /controller/action/delete?id= or sth. It must be send via ajax with POST method.

Comment: yes i do have filter + that code,this my url,but using this it shows error 400,request invalid!wher i have change,in model,controller or in cgridview,where do i have to put post method!or any changes in action admin or somewhere,can u refer me of delete for cgidview!

Comment: hey thanks..it is finally working..it wasi didn't mention ajaxupdate,which has to be mention in cgridview admin page,when i used it..it worked finally..thanks for ur answer..thnkxx..

Answer (score 0):

What does deleteDService() do? If you extend your Model from CActiveRecord, your model will inherit a delete() method.

Comment: deleteDService($id){
try{
$sql="DELETE discount_service.* FROM discount_service WHERE discount_service.id=$id";
   $connection=Yii::app()->db;
   $transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute();
$transaction->commit();
}catch (Exception $e){
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error',$e);
$this->flash=Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error');
$this->f=1;
$transaction->rollBack();
}return;
} it is my deleteDService from the model!if i change delete to remove in controller and access rules it is working through URL,but delete method is not working

Comment: hey thanks..it is finally working..it wasi didn't mention ajaxupdate,which has to be mention in cgridview admin page,when i used it..it worked finally..thanks for ur answer..thnkxx..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, If you load more than one jquery.js lib file, cgridview delete function and most of ajax functions will not work.